Find all diagonalisable matrices $M$ such that $M^2=\begin{pmatrix} 3 & 1\\ -2 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$
This question follows the proof for \begin{equation} A=PDP^{-1}\implies A^n=PD^nP^{-1} \end{equation} where $D$ is matrix with eigenvalues of A as diagonals and $P$ is the matrix with the corresponding eigenvectors as columns.
I've tried setting up a system of equations by choosing some matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d \end{pmatrix}$ such that $A^2=M^2$, but don't think I can find all the solutions that way. I'm pretty sure that some work needs to be done with eigenvalues and eigenvectors but I can't seem to think of it.

A matrix $M$ is diagonalizable if and only if there exist $P$ and $D$ such that
\begin{equation*}
M = PDP^{-1}
\end{equation*}
where $D$ is diagonal and $P$ is invertible. Then
\begin{equation*}
M^{2} = PDP^{-1}PDP^{-1} = PD^{2}P^{-1}.
\end{equation*}
Now the entries of $D$ are the eigenvalues of $M$, and since $D$ is diagonal,
\begin{equation*}
D^{2} = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
\lambda_{1}^{2} & 0\\
0 & \lambda_{2}^{2}
\end{array}\right).
\end{equation*}
Therefore
\begin{equation*}
M^{2} = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
3 & 1\\
-2 & 0
\end{array}\right) = P\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\lambda_{1}^{2} & 0\\
0 & \lambda_{2}^{2}
\end{array}\right)
P^{-1}.
\end{equation*}
In other words, you can diagonalize $M$ and $M^{2}$ with the same $P$--diagonalize $M^{2}$ to find such a $P$. But from the previous equation, can you tell why there might be more than one diagonalizable matrix $M$ such that $M^{2}$ is as given?

Eigenvalues differ by sign (such that their squares are still identical to those of $D^2$?

@PeterChen Exactly, such that their squares are identical to those of $D^{2}$ and those of $M^{2}$. And then for each satisfactory pair of eigenvalues, you can write down a matrix $D$ and a corresponding matrix $M = PDP^{-1}$ such that $M^{2}$ is as given!

Let $N=\begin{pmatrix} 3 & 1 \\ -2 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ that has eigenvalues $1, 2$. Hence by spectral mapping theorem, $M$ must have eigenvalues $a, b$ such that $a^2=1$ and $b^2=2$. In total, there are four possibilities for the pair $(a,b)$. In each possibility, $a\not=b$, therefore $M$ can be diagonalized, with eigenvectors $v_a, v_b$. And $v_a, v_b$ must be also eigenvectors of $N$ as well.
Therefore $v_a=\alpha\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -2 \end{pmatrix}, v_b=\beta\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}$, where $\alpha,\beta$ are nonzero scalars. And WLOG, we may assume $\alpha=\beta=1$, so $M$ is
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ -2 & -1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} a &  \\  & b \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ -2 & -1 \end{pmatrix}^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix} -a+2b & -a+b \\ 2a-2b & 2a-b\end{pmatrix}$$
There are in total only four solutions. The method can be used to solve $M^n=N$ for any integer $n$ and $N$ with only distinct eigenvalues.
